# how to show the principal branch of log(z) equal to an integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that the principal branch of the log function can be described by the formula $log(z)=\int_1^z \frac{1}{w} dw$ for $z \not \in (-\infty,0]$.

Thank you everyone in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $z=re^{i\theta}$, where $\vert\theta\vert<\pi$ (so that we do not pass through the deleted ray).

Then $\log z=\log r+i\theta$ is the principal branch of the logarithm. One has

$$\log z=\log r+i\theta = \log r + \int_0^\theta \frac{ire^{it}}{re^{it}}dt=\int_1^r \frac{1}{w}\,dw+\int_\gamma \frac{1}{w}dw$$

where $\gamma$ is the arc from $r$ to $z$. Now this yields a path integration from $1$ to $\vert z\vert$ on the real line and then along the arc to $z$. But by Cauchy's Theorem on a simply connected domain (since $\log z$ is holomorphic in the complex plane with the deleted ray, and the complex plane with the deleted ray is simply connected), one has (where the integral from $z$ to $1$ means integration over any arbitrary curve from $z$ to $1$ that does not pass through the deleted ray)

$$\int_1^r\frac{1}{w}dw+\int_\gamma\frac{1}{w}dw+\int_z^1\frac{1}{w}dw=0$$

Hence, reversing the orientation on the curve from $z$ to $1$, we have

$$\int_1^r\frac{1}{w}dw+\int_\gamma\frac{1}{w}dw=\int_1^z\frac{1}{w}dw$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** Consider the derivative of both $\log(z)$ and $\displaystyle\int_1^{\large z}\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{w}$

**Hint 2:** Use [Cauchy's Integral Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem) to show that this integral does not depend on the path from $1$ to $z$ as long as the path does not cross $(-\infty,0]$.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer to my own question. It is pretty much an one-liner if one just applies the FTC for complex number.

Comment: You'll need to prove that $\log z$ is a primitive of $1/w$, which does not exactly make your life easier.

Comment: Oh well forgot about that. Thanks